# Resizing tableview height programmatically

Tags: xcode, resize, height, tableview

I am using storyboard in xcode 4.5.

In my application there is 2 views, view1 and view2.

Each view has a tableview.

A navigation controller is connected to the views.

I am trying to change the height of the tableview depending on the size of the Iphone display.

I am using the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewDidAppear:animated];    

// Verify if the screen is iphone 5

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568){

    // Resize table hight

    CGRect tvframe = [_myTableView frame];
    [_myTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(tvframe.origin.x,
                                      tvframe.origin.y,
                                      tvframe.size.width,
                                      tvframe.size.height + 64)];
}
```

The problem is that the code has no effect when the application starts and view1 appears.

But when I move to view2 and then back to view1 the resizing takes effect.

I don't understand why the reszing doesn't take effect when the application starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried moving the code to ViewWillAppear? That should fix the problem.

Comment: Moving the code to ViewWillAppear doesn't work.

I solved the problem by creating separate views, those for Iphone 3/4 and those for Iphone 5.